# Issue with security certificate name

Tags: https, security-certificate

I have inherited an old website whose security certificate causes this error when viewed with IE.

"The name on the security certificate is invalid or does not match the name of the site"

Is there any easy way to fix this without having to get a new certificate?

**Edit**:
Some more info. This an internal website, though a couple of other companies have secure access to out networks DMZ to access it.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not the www/non-www issue that John mentions then you could put an entry in your DNS for the name that's on the certificate, but you'll have to tell people to use the new name.

Comment: So in other words the name in the cert cannot be changed? That's what I figured.

Comment: Yes, that's part of why it's secure.

Answer (score 1):

A common reason for this to occur is the SSL certificate is for example.com and the URL being accessed is www.example.com or vice versa. With the exception of wildcard certificates, they are issued for specific domains/subdomains and even just adding or removing the 'www' will cause issues.

If this is the case for your website an easy fix is to automatically forward users to the 'www' or 'non-www' URL with a 301 redirect. This can be done with a simple snippet in .htaccess for Apache and probably is just as easy in IIS.